# Completement of an infinite set

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of all primes over $\mathbb{Z}$ and define $P(a):=\{p\in\mathcal{P}:\,p|a\}.\ $ One can show that for any given non-constant polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the set $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}P(f(n))$ is an infinite set. My question is what conditions should one impose on $f(x)$ so that one obtains the equality $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}P(f(n))=\mathcal{P}$. I was wondering if anyone can suggest a paper that deals with similar kind of questions.

Comment: Your "any given polynomial" is non-constant, right?

Comment: You are asking in the wrong forum.

Comment: Where is the appropriate place to post this question?

Comment: Trivial observation: Any polynomial that has a linear factor satisfies your condition. Moreover, for quadratic polynomials I think that the converse follows trivially from this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135820/does-there-exist-a-non-square-number-which-is-the-quadratic-residue-of-every-pri

Comment: *Trivial observation: Any polynomial that has a linear factor satisfies your condition.* Obviously not: $(5+6n)^{10}$ is never divisible by $3$ (or $2$)

Comment: @NickS I think you mean polynomials with monic linear factors. But that is the trivial case as the polynomial then has an integer root. My polynomial should not have any integer root.

Comment: The polynomials fulfilling this equality (or maybe the (only slightly) stronger variant where you demand existence of a root modulo all integers rather than all primes) are sometimes called intersective. See https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-06/S0002-9939-96-03210-8/S0002-9939-96-03210-8.pdf for most basic properties and examples. In a nutshell, they need to be (linear or) reducible, and the factors have to ``fit together" in a concrete (Galois-theoretical) sense.